# How do you merge User folders/accounts in a Win7/Win10 dual boot setup

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, multi-boot, windows-10-upgrade

I just installed Win10 over Win7 in a dual boot config - it works fine. I 1) upgraded in place to activate my Win10 license, 2) reverted back to Win7, then 3) did a clean install of Win10 to a new partition from a USB drive.

But my user accounts/folders are separate. Is there an easy way to point Win10 to use the SAME user account folders as Win7?

Comment: That would be a bad idea...  Security permissions, shared temporary spaces, certificate repositories, etc. is just asking for pain (IMO).

Comment: would it be better to manually change the location of user folders to the same destination? 

Win10 'Documents' => U:\Users\[user]\documents <= Win7 'My Documents'

Comment: And what do dual boot'ers do about common public folders, i.e. videos.